# Using Japanese password with KeyStore.load() causes java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, unicode, keystore

I have created a Keystore using:

> keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias myself

and the password i have given is in Japanese i.e. "myPasswordは"
I am using the following code to load the keystore file

```
String KEYSTORE_FILE="C:/myKeyStore";//Path to the keystore file on disk.
PASSWORD="myPasswordは";//Password

KeyStore.getInstance("JKS").load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE),PASSWORD.toCharArray());
```

The above throws the following exception:
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

If i create the keystore using an english password and use the same in code then it works fine.

Initially I created the keystore using the command:
*keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias mks*
this will prompt me for the password which i enter as myPasswordは and then i enter the subsequent details. In this case, the code generates the above exception.

The interesting thing is that if i create the keystore using :
*keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias mks -storepass myPasswordは*
then the code that i have given above works fine. I am using linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is that the keytool utility does not decode a non-ascii password entered at prompt correctly.

This is a known issue which can be found at https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=53546691146578386c644cb554976?bug_id=6433238

So, the solution is to create a keystore with a password not entered at prompt. This can be done in the following way:

keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias myAlias -storepass すてきなパスワード

Answer (score 2):

Well, from the description I guess that console doesn't process unicode characters as expected. You can try to use PowerShell or try to change code page of cmd.exe to UTF-8 by executing `chcp 65001` command (note that this will distort console display behaviour, but it will accept input properly).