# Using PCKS#12 certifcate with non-ASCII password

Tags: java, pkcs#12, java-security

I trying to open PKCS#12 file, but because password is not ASCII (contains polish characters) I getting "Password is not ASCII" exception when executing KeyStore.load(). Is there any solution to using this certificate?

Comment: Do you use `keytool` to generate keystore file? Can you regenerate file? If yes, take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811950/using-japanese-password-with-keystore-load-causes-java-io-ioexception-keystor

Comment: No. Certificate was generated by other software and different company.

Comment: Piotr S, did you find a solution?

Comment: In theory you may still use openssl to change the keystore password to something reasonable

Comment: Assuming you're using KeyStore.load​(InputStream stream, char[] password), you can encode your password array with a specific locale. What is the source of the array? Typing it? Bytestream? Reader?

Comment: Stacktrace would be helpful. The PKCS12 format in Java allows only ASCII (' '..'~'), you'll need to change the password: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971837/changing-password-on-p12-file

Comment: The mere existence of the "Password is not ASCII" exception seems to be a bug. RFC 7292 specifically allows UTF-8 encoding for the password. The [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream,char%5B%5D)) specifies char[], and in Java char is UTF-16, so there is no reason to disallow non-ASCII characters.

Comment: simple workaround: base64 the password

Answer (score 5):

The [RFC 7292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#appendix-B.1) specifies the support of ASCII and UTF-8 encodings for passwords as a recommendation only.

[Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#load(java.io.InputStream,char%5B%5D)) supports only ASCII passwords.

So, the workaround is to change the keystore password.

## Example

Generate private key and certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj "/CN=test/C=CH/ST=Zurich/L=Zurich/O=Test Org/OU=Test Unit"
```

Create a PKCS 12 keystore with a non-ASCII password (`пароль`)

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out keystore.p12 -password pass:пароль
```

Get the PKCS 12 keystore info using OpenSSL

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in keystore.p12 -noout -password pass:пароль
```

Trying to get the keystore info using Java `keytool` results in exception `Password is not ASCII`

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass пароль -storetype PKCS12

java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2108)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:946)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.io.IOException: getSecretKey failed: Password is not ASCII
```

So, the keystore password has to be changed.
There is no easy way to change a PKCS 12 keystore password using OpenSSL.
The existing keystore has to be converted to PEM and a new keystore with a new password has to be created instead

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -out keystore.txt -nodes -password pass:пароль
openssl pkcs12 -export -in keystore.txt -out newkeystore.p12 -password pass:password
rm keystore.txt
```

Don't forget to do the last step to remove unencrypted PEM key.

Now, it's possible to get the keytool info using both OpenSSL and Java keytool

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in newkeystore.p12 -noout -password pass:password
keytool -list -v -keystore newkeystore.p12 -storepass password -storetype PKCS12

Your keystore contains 1 entry
```

Usually, it's better to use Java keytool to change a keystore password as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900084/7873775

```
keytool -storetype pkcs12 -keystore newkeystore.p12 -storepasswd -storepass password -new newpassword
```

But it doesn't work for keystores with non-ASCII passwords.

Answer (score 1):

i have change my password "889002333" to "amrajat" and my error solve

Comment: Maybe you should consider not publishing your certificate passwords over the internet.